# Logistic regression using ANOVA kernel in SKLearn?

Tags: logistic, classification, python, scikit-learn

In RapidMiner, you can run a logistic regression classifier with multiple kernel types. I see no options in `sklearn.linear_models.LogisticRegression`.

Does anybody know if there is an easy way to implement this in SKLearn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

scikit-learn, unfortunately, currently supports neither kernel logistic regression nor the ANOVA kernel.

There are some workarounds, though.

The idea of the kernel trick is: since many algorithms access the data only through inner products $\langle x, y \rangle$, we can map our inputs $x$ into some feature space $\varphi(x)$, which can actually be any Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, if we can compute $\langle \varphi(x), \varphi(y) \rangle_{\mathcal H}$ as $k(x, y)$. Then we don't have to do the actual mapping $\varphi$, which is often infinite-dimensional.

But, it turns out that we can often find a function $z$, where $z(x) \in \mathbb R^D$, such that $z(x)^T z(y) \approx \langle \varphi(x), \varphi(y) \rangle_{\mathcal H}$. Then we can run standard logistic regression on the $z(x)$ features, and we'll get approximately the result of kernel logistic regression.

#### Option 1: Cholesky

The Gram matrix $K$, where $K_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$, is all the data we need to run a method. But $K$ is necessarily positive semi-definite, and for the ANOVA kernel, I believe that it is always nonsingular as well. Thus there is some matrix $R$ such that $K = R R^T$, i.e. $K$ is the Gram matrix of $R$. So you can compute $K$ yourself, and then use $R$ as the features.

This approach is exact, but the logistic regression model will be slow, since the dimensionality is equal to the number of inputs, and it can't be extended to new points easily (so you need to know what the test points are at training time).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import check_pairwise_arrays

def anova_kernel(X, Y=None, gamma=None, p=1):
    X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
    if gamma is None:
        gamma = 1. / X.shape[1]

    diff = X[:, None, :] - Y[None, :, :]
    diff **= 2
    diff *= -gamma
    np.exp(diff, out=diff)
    K = diff.sum(axis=2)
    K **= p
    return K


from scipy.linalg import cholesky
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# make X the matrix of all data points, train + test
# train is indices of train points, test of test
K = anova_kernel(X)
R = cholesky(K, lower=False)
clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(R[train], y_train)
preds = clf.predict(R[test])
```

I don't recommend this; it's just here for completeness.

Note in the `anova_kernel` function above that it doesn't do the thing [rapidminer does](https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-studio/blob/8b53df4608a0fccc452510efcc4b54745f466129/src/main/java/com/rapidminer/tools/math/kernels/AnovaKernel.java#L56) in "double-counting" points where they're both zero. I don't know why it does that; none of the other definitions of the anova kernel I've seen do.

#### Option 2: Nyström

This is an approximate kernel embedding which works by assuming that the kernel matrix $K$ is low-rank – which it almost always is. In Nyström, you pick a set of $D$ data points, then compute the full kernel evaluation of all the $n$ points to only those $D$ points. If you pick the first $D$ points, then the kernel matrix looks like:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
B^T & ?
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where you've computed $A$ (the pairwise kernel evaluations among the $D$ points) and $B$ (the kernel evaluations from each of the other points to the $D$ points), and $?$ will be guessed based on the assumption that $K$ is rank $D$. It turns out that the way to do that is to eigendecompose $A = U \Lambda U^T$, and then use the features $Z = \begin{bmatrix}U \Lambda^{\tfrac12} \\ B^T U \Lambda^\dagger \Lambda^{\tfrac12}\end{bmatrix}$.

Compared to Cholesky, this approach is inexact, but gives a low-dimensional embedding, and easily allows extension to new data points. Plus, it's already implemented in [`sklearn.kernel_approximation.Nystroem`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.kernel_approximation.Nystroem.html#sklearn.kernel_approximation.Nystroem).

```
from sklearn.kernel_approximation import Nystroem
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

K_train = anova_kernel(X_train)
clf = Pipeline([
    ('nys', Nystroem(kernel='precomputed', n_components=100)),
    ('lr', LogisticRegression())
])
clf.fit(K_train, y_train)

K_test = anova_kernel(X_test, X_train)
preds = clf.predict(K_test)
```

#### Option 3: Random Fourier Features

The other major paradigm of approximate kernel embeddings is random Fourier features (also sometimes called "random kitchen sinks"). These work on shift-invariant kernels $k(x, y) = k(x - y)$ by taking the Fourier transform of $k$, which by Bochner's theorem will be (scalable to) a probability distribution, sampling $\{\omega_i\}_{i=1}^{D/2}$ from it, and then using the feature map
$$z(x) = \begin{bmatrix}\sin(\omega_1^T x) & \cos(\omega_1^T x) & \dots & \sin(\omega_{D/2}^T x) & \cos(\omega_{D/2}^T x)\end{bmatrix}.$$
(Sometimes you'll see this as $\cos(\omega_i^T X + b_i)$ instead, but this way [is better](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02785).)

scikit-learn has these implemented for RBF and some variants of $\chi^2$ kernels, but not for ANOVA. But the kernel is shift-invariant:

$$
k(\Delta)
= \left( \sum_{i=1}^d \exp(-\gamma \Delta_i^2) \right)^p
$$

The problem is, I don't know how to Fourier transform it. :)
For $d = 1$, it's a Gaussian with mean 0 and variance $2 p \gamma$. For $p = 1$, $d > 1$, you can do it by getting an embedding for each dimension and concatenating them together.

For integer $p$, you might be able to turn the product of sums into a sum of products and then Fourier transform each term, I suppose. Don't think that'd generalize to non-integral $p$, and I haven't tried it for integral $p > 1$ yet either.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is admittedly way over my head. I've tried to find an ANOVA kernel for Python, but have only found one that takes x,y inputs which I'm not sure I understand in my case. Do you have a recommendation for finding a suitable anova kernel for this purpose?

Comment: @user1566200 I'd recommend trying approach 2 with a fairly large `n_components` (maybe 1000). This will be approximate, but closer to exact (and slower) the higher you set that. The `anova_kernel` function under the code block in approach 1 should work, though you'll need to tune `gamma` and `p` somehow. This is similar to rapidminer's anova kernel, though if you want it exactly identical (including a weird thing they do that other sources don't) I can show you how to change that.